# Eclipse Clover Plugin / Toggling Code Coverage Highlighting on Editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, junit, code-coverage, clover

I have recently been using Clover plugin for Eclipse and it's been incredibly useful. Perhaps the most useful part - the code coverage highlighting however is turning out to be incredibly annoying when writing/composing JUNIT tests.

I was just wondering, is there an easy way to turn the highlighting off and back on with click of a button or keyboard shortcut. Note that I do not like to entirely turn off and disable clover coverage on a project. I just merely need to turn off the green/red highlighting on code inside the editor when I am writing my JUNITs. Is there any easy way to do that? I did lot of research myself and could not find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using three buttons named "Show all / Show uncovered / Show none" from the Coverage Explorer view? They're located near the top-right corner of this view.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/2.+Exploration+of+coverage+in+Eclipse